# Ember.js component with HTML input range does not set value correctly

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I have a simple Ember component that only contains a single input range slider, like so:

```
<input
  type="range"
  value=500
  min=0
  max=500
>
```

When it renders initially, the slider's position is not set to the very end as you would expect. It is set at around the 100 position.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to change the order of the attributes and set the value after the max:

```
<input
  type="range"
  min=0
  max=500
  value=500
>
```

Normally in HTML the order of the attributes does not matter. However, in this case Ember seems to be converting it into something along the lines of:

```
let input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type', 'range');
input.setAttribute('value', 500);
input.setAttribute('min', 0);
input.setAttribute('max', 500);
```

The [default max of an input is 100](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#Specifying_the_minimum_and_maximum). In this case, setting the 'value' to 500 before setting the 'max' is invalid so it gets set to 100 instead.

See discussion [here](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/2427).